# Does someone have a recommendation for an editor that will provide feedback during execution and allow you to preview a page while working on it?

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I need something I can use to see variable values etc. during execution for debugging JS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can debug Javascript using firebug.(firefox addon)

Answer (score 0):

The Big 3 Browsers (IE, FF, and Chrome) all have tools & add-ins that will let you do rich debugging and drill into the HTML, DOM, and CSS.  I use all 3 and find that each one has its strengths.

However, if you can afford it the best editor in my opinion is Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really enjoying using the [Cloud9 Ide](http://c9.io) for doing work where I need integrated debugging and step-by-step code execution in my server side javascript. Cloud 9 is free and browser-based, it's worth checking out if you're serious about javascript development.

If I need that for client-side script, then I've found the debugging tools and REPL in chrome to be more than sufficient.